# Executing Memgraph's GQLAlchemy

Tags: docker, graph-databases, memgraphdb

I have the Memgraph platform running inside Docker. How can I execute the GQLAlchemy script on that platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just execute the Python script (e.g. python3 script.py). It is important you first create a memgraph instance:

```
from gqlalchemy import Memgraph 
memgraph = Memgraph("127.0.0.1", 7687)
```

This means that you are communicating with Memgraph (at port 7687, via Bolt protocol). Therefore, whenever you run some command with memgraph, it will be executed at your Memgraph instance which is running on port 7687.
The important thing is that Memgraph Platform is running and then we can just execute Python commands in order to communicate with Memgraph.